# Get Textbox Value from Masterpage using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a search textbox situated on a masterpage like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="frmSearch" runat="server" CssClass="searchbox"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:LinkButton ID="searchGo" PostBackUrl="search.aspx"  runat="server">GO</asp:LinkButton>
```

The code behind for the search page has the following to pick up the textbox value (snippet):

```
if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack)
        {
            Page previousPage = PreviousPage;
            TextBox tbSearch = (TextBox)PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("frmSearch");
            searchValue.Text = tbSearch.Text;

            //more code here...
        }
```

All works great. BUT not if you enter a value whilst actually on search.aspx, which obviously isn't a previous page. How can I get round this dead end I've put myself in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [`@MasterType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in the page directive, then you will have a strongly-typed master page, meaning you can access exposed properties, controls, et cetera, without the need the do lookups:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="MasterSourceType.master" %>

searchValue.Text = PreviousPage.Master.frmSearch.Text;
```

EDIT: In order to help stretch your imagination a little, consider an extremely simple property exposed by the master page:

```
public string SearchQuery 
{
    get { return frmSearch.Text; }
    set { frmSearch.Text = value; }
}
```

Then, through no stroke of ingenuity whatsoever, it can be seen that we can access it like so:

```
searchValue.Text = PreviousPage.Master.SearchQuery;
```

Or,

```
PreviousPage.Master.SearchQuery = "a query";
```

Comment: +1 - Correct I used to do this when working with web forms and found it handy enough to [write a bit about it](http://www.matthewedmondson.info/2009/11/using-mastertype-directive-instead-of.html)

Comment: I wouldn't take this so literally; you can expose a `string` property which can `get` and/or `set` the text of the private control.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully this should be straightforward enough.

Comment: thank you for your help and patience. I'm very new to .net and the penny hasn't really dropped yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (but I guess its old now):

```
    {
        if (PreviousPage == null)
        {
            TextBox tbSearch = (TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtSearch");
            searchValue.Value = tbSearch.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox tbSearch = (TextBox)PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("txtSearch");
            searchValue.Value = tbSearch.Text;             
        }
    }
```